# Alternating SQL queries

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm looking for a way to implement alternating SQL queries - i.e. a function that allows me to filter entries based on different columns. Take the following example:

```
el=[["a","b",1],["a","b",3]]    

def save_sql(foo):
    with sqlite3.connect("fn.db") as db:
        cur=db.cursor()
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS et"
                    "(var1 VARCHAR, var2 VARCHAR, var3 INT)")
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO et VALUES "
                        "(?,?,?)", foo)
        db.commit()

def load_sql(v1,v2,v3): 
    with sqlite3.connect("fn.db") as db:
        cur=db.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM et WHERE var1=? AND var2=? AND var3=?", (v1,v2,v3))
        return cur.fetchall()

save_sql(el)
```

Now if I were to use `load_sql("a","b",1)`, it would work. But assume I want to only query for the first and third column, i.e. `load_sql("a",None,1)` (the `None` is just intended as a placeholder) or only the last column `load_sql(None,None,5)`, this wouldn't work.

This could of course be done with if statements checking which variables were supplied in the function call, but in tables with larger amounts of columns, this might get messy.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: so you're looking for a way to modify the SQL query to have the correct number of constraints given a variable number of columns, is that correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if `load_sql()` would accept an arbitrary number of keyword arguments, where keyword argument names would correspond to column names. Something along these lines:

```
def load_sql(**values): 
    with sqlite3.connect("fn.db") as db:
        cur = db.cursor() 

        query = "SELECT * FROM et"
        conditions = [f"{column_name} = :{column_name}" for column_name in values]

        if conditions:
            query = query + " WHERE " + " AND ".join(conditions)
        cur.execute(query, values)
        return cur.fetchall()
```

Note that here we trust keyword argument names to be valid and existing column names (and string-format them into the query) which may potentially be used as an SQL injection attack vector.

As a side note, I cannot stop but think that this feels like a reinventing-the-wheel step towards an actual ORM. Look into lightweight [`PonyORM`](https://ponyorm.com/) or [Peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) abstraction layers between Python and a database.

Answer (score 2):

It will inevitably get messy if you want your SQL statements to remain sanitized/safe, but as long as you control your function signature it can remain reasonably safe, e.g.:

```
def load_sql(var1, var2, var3):
    fields = dict(field for field in locals().items() if field[1] is not None)
    query = "SELECT * FROM et"
    if fields:  # if at least one field is not None:
        query += " WHERE " + " AND ".join((k + "=?" for k in fields.keys()))
    with sqlite3.connect("fn.db") as db:
        cur = db.cursor()
        cur.execute(query, fields.values())
        return cur.fetchall()
```

You can replace the function signature with `load_sql(**kwargs)` and then use `kwargs.items()` instead of `locals.items()` so that you can pass arbitrary column names, but that can be very dangerous and is certainly not recommended.